# Display Multi-field Checkbox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, form

I have a MultiField Choice list item. By default it displays:

> Choice 1, Choice 2, Choice 3, Choice 4,

I  would like it to display like the following.

> Choice 1,
>   Choice 2,
>   Choice 3,
>   Choice 4

I have tried using various versions of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = clear(); 
  function clear() { 
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.replace(',', 'br'); 
  } 
</script>
```

However when I use this code the whole page is blank.

I also used this script with limited success

```
<button onclick="ChangeText()">Button</button>

<script>
function ChangeText() {
  var str = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(",", "[br]");
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

This would only change one line and on clicking the button.

I have a feeling I am making this more complicated then it needs to be.